# SendGrid / PHP - Why am I sending and receiving duplicate emails?

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I am attempting to use SendGrid to send emails in PHP. I am using the sample code provided by SendGrid and emails are sending, but each time I send I receive TWO duplicate emails in the inbox. There are no log errors or indication that the emails are being duplicated. I am only calling the code once and I can't find any reason why I would receive two duplicate email. Any insight would be much appreciated.

```
function sendEmaill(){
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom("xxxx@yyyyy.com", "Testing");
$email->setSubject("Your Registration is confirmed");
$email->addTo("aaaaa@bbbbbbb.com", "Test");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "Your Registration for X is confirmed");
$email->addContent(
"text/html", "<strong>If you have any questions please contact XXXXX</strong>"
);

$apiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Replace with your actual SendGrid API key

$sendgrid = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
try {
$response = $sendgrid->send($email);
print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
print_r($response->headers());
print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
header("Location: /account/registration/index.php?c=123");
exit();
}
```

Comment: Based on the code provided alone, you wouldn't receive duplicates. I use Sendgrid myself, and mine does not duplicate. We'd need to see more of your code to troubleshoot possible issues.

Comment: Dump the full headers of both messages (as receivied by the client) and then post the diff between them.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was testing this function by loading it on page in my browser, which was causing the function to run twice. When I included the function separately (in an included "Functions" file), it only sends the email once. Hope this helps someone.